# How can I detect if a browser is IE 8 or IE 9 without Javascript?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have seen the following:

[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

But this does not really show how I can detect for IE8 or IE9. Can someone tell me how I can do this with conditional comments?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, you linked an article to the conditional comments?

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted is correct. Those comments are what you need.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)|(IE 9)]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or 9<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Conditional Comments (for your reference):
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Between the square brackets are your conditions, you can do equals, not equals, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, greater than or equal to.

Comment: But how can I combine these into one line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional comments in Internet Explorer to add a CSS class to your HTML node. This is how html5boilerplate works to add browser specific CSS:

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For each browser you can use different kind of "conditional comments" 
here is one of very good article by  Chris Coyier over this issue.

http://css-tricks.com/new-poll-conditional-tags-for-all-browsers/

it is my personal experience it was good to use conditional comments.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can detect ie8 and 9 also. Try this

```
<!--[if IE]><p>You are using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->
<![if !IE]><p>You are not using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]>

<!--[if IE 8]><p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8!</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 9)]><p>You are not using version 9.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]><p>You are using IE 8 or greater.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 5)]><p>You are using IE 5 (any version).</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 5.5)&(lt IE 7)]><p>You are using IE 5.5 or IE 6.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 5.5]><p>Please upgrade your version of Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if true]>You are using an <em>uplevel</em> browser.<![endif]-->
<![if false]>You are using a <em>downlevel</em> browser.<![endif]>

<!--[if true]><![if IE 7]><p>This nested comment is displayed in IE 7.</p><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

In the `if` condition expresions `lte` denotes less than or equal to and `gte` denoted greater than or equal to and `lt` denotes less than.